# RecyclerView scrolling perfomance with Gradle Plugin 2.0 alpha

Tags: android, plugins, scroll, gradle, android-recyclerview

I tried to do some search but haven't found anything.

I'll try to add items on my recycler view with the method `notifyItemRangeInserted` and i'll notice bad scrolling performance only with `Gradle Plugin 2.0 alpha`.
When i add these items on my recycler view using `Gradle Plugin 1.5`, i have no problem.

I don't understand what the problem is, do you have any ideas ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure that it depends by the plugin? Gradle is not related to the runtime (except the Instant Run feature)

Comment: By default instant run is activate when you create a new project android studio 2.0 but to work, Gradle Plugin 2.0 is necessary. i didn't notice that so when i set Gradle Plugin 1.5 it disable instant run and the recycler view have no scrolling issue. The issue not depend on gradle plugin but on instant run. I don't know how can instant run can cause this issue. Thanks you